# Why does .fadeOut() not work, but .hide() works fine when hiding appended div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to show a div and remove it after few seconds. It's just that easy.
So in my html I've got: `<div id="msg"></div>`

And I've got this function:

```
function showWarning(text) {
            $('<div>'+text+'</div>').appendTo('#msg').hide().fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).queue(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }
```

I can't find any way to make this work. `fadeOut()` is called but nothing happens on screen.
If I change `fadeOut()` to `hide()` it works fine. However... If I try `hide(500)` then it won't work.

I assume this is something trivial - beginner mistake - but I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using `.queue()` for?

Comment: I read here on SO that it wouldn't work without `.queue()`... didn't test it. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fadeIn()` must not be finished running, use a callback function instead before doing your fadeOut.

```
$('<div>'+text+'</div>').appendTo('#msg').hide().fadeIn('fast', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function showWarning(text) {
    $('<div />', {text: text}).fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(600);
    }).appendTo('#msg');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNuPZ/)

Answer (score 1):

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/b7EV8/

```
function showWarning(text) {
    $('<div id="msgtext">' + text + '</div>').appendTo('#msg').hide().fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#msgtext').delay(1000).fadeOut();
    });
}

showWarning('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function showWarning(text) {
  $('<div>').text(text).appendTo('#msg').hide().fadeTo(400,1,function(){
      $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut();
  });
}
```

### *[demo](http://jsbin.com/ataqoy/1/edit)*